# Rails Migration Column Added But Not Populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I'm trying to write a very simple Rails migration that adds a new column to the table and populates it with a combination of data from other columns. However, the column gets added but the column value is nil for every record. What am I doing wrong?

```
class AddNameToPermissions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :auth_permissions, :name, :string
    Auth::Permission.reset_column_information
    Auth::Permission.all.each do |permission|
      target_name = permission.target_symbol || permission.target_class
      permission.name = permission.action << ", " << target_name
      permission.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling permission.save will execute all the callbacks including validators and maybe a validator is preventing the record to be saved. To skip validators you can use update_column instead of save

```
permission.update_column(:name, permission.action << ", " << target_name)
```

Also I would recommend you a couple of tips:

- Use Auth::Permission.find_each instead of Auth::Permission.all.each (this loads all the records at once in memory)
- Try to update the permission in a rake task and use only the migration to modify the table (it is the recommended good practice way)

Comment: Changing it to update_column didn't work either. I had to write a custom SQL query to do it. Still not sure why it didn't go through.

Comment: Is there a reason to make a rake task for updating the values of the new column instead of just running a loop similar to the one modeled above from the server console?

Comment: @sixty4bit I am generally wary of anything I run right off the server console instead of writing a data migration or custom rake task since it's not checked into version control, hard to keep track of and as a result easy to forget to manage in case a rollback is ever required.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the default option in a migration, it is usually advisable to do that in a custom rake task.  Content Migrations are a bit of an anti pattern.  The main Logic you want there is anything that has to deal with the schema of your database. Run your migration with only the `add_column` line, and then write a rake task to transfer the values from one table to the other.